# What north atlantic fish can we use to make a good ceviche?

Tags: fish, seafood, marinade, lemon, ceviche

I am planning to do a ceviche entrée in Ireland but I am limited in the choice of seafood and most likely won't find Peruvian/Pacific ones. Any recommendations for? substitutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think just about any large flaky-fleshed fish that's not too fatty is a good candidate for ceviche. Salmon can work, though it's a tad fatty. Tuna is not a good choice, in my opinion. Cod and any kind of bass can work really well. I would think haddock or even sole or flounder could work too.

There is lots of white-fleshed fish available in the North Atlantic, and many will do great in ceviche. Take a look at the flesh and see if it seems similar to what you would usually use, and when in doubt ask the fishmonger for advice. Even if they don't know ceviche, if you can tell them what fish you'd usually use, they can probably advise you on substitutes.

Comment: Yes - I did more research on the side, apparently any fish that is not too red or compact will work (hence shellfish and shrimps). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tuna, Shrimp, Squid, Mackerel, etc. should all be available in your area to some degree.  Any of them would be great ingredients.

Comment: It's unfortunate I can't have all of them :) but squid will definitely go into the pot. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

I'm a sucker for Tilapia, seems to work out quite well

Comment: [Tilapia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilapia) is a fresh water fish.